# delete first line of file only if blank using sed

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, sed, tcsh

I have a solution for this in `awk`:

```
awk '{if (NR==1 && NF==0) next};1' somefile
```

but was unable to find one that worked in `sed`. E.g.,

```
sed -i.bak '/^$/{1,1d;}' somefile
```

ended up deleting the first blank line it found (I'm not a `sed` expert, so I was just trying out things). The advantage to `sed` in this case is that I would be able to do this w/o temporary files. ie in place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sed '1{/^$/d}' file
```

Comment: It can't delete the first line if it isn't blank. Please check how it works and write if it is ok.

Comment: I understand the `/^$/d` part, by putting the line number in front and enclosing it in `{}` makes it only apply to that line? I assume I could also give a range of line numbers in the form 2,4 (start at line 2 and end at 4)?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

> sed '0,/^$/d' file

And as a bold guessing, you may want to delete all the blank lines before the first line(containing any chars), if it is the case, we can try the below:

> sed '1,/^$/d' file